# Why are `netmask`, `network`, `gateway` and `dns-nameservers` needed for setting up a static IP?

Tags: networking, ip

When setting up a static IP,  you need to change `/etc/network/interfaces` to:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address 10.253.0.50
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   network 10.253.0.0
   gateway 10.253.0.1
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Why are `netmask`, `network`, `gateway` and `dns-nameservers` needed for setting up a static IP?

Why are they not used when setting up a dynamic IP (e.g. by DHCP)?

Comment: I'm not answering because I'm reading around now, as you mentioned the cause seems to be exactly the DHCP rotocol, which not used if statical ip is configured. DHCP distribute this informations dynamically

Answer (score 3):

With DHCP, the *server* normally provides all of that information:

- routing (the network, gateway and netmask)
- the actual DNS servers

There are special cases where you can provide some or all of this, e.g., as described in *[Supplying routing information using DHCP](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/471/Supplying_routing_information_using_DHCP)*.

For small private networks, it is common to use a router as a DHCP server (reducing the problem to routing *to/from* the router).  That does not scale up well:

- [Still Using DHCP On Your Routers? You Can’t Do That With IPv6!](https://community.infoblox.com/t5/IPv6-Center-of-Excellence/Still-Using-DHCP-On-Your-Routers-You-Can-t-Do-That-With-IPv6/ba-p/3431)
- [How to Configure a Router to Use DHCP](http://www.wikihow.com/Configure-a-Router-to-Use-DHCP)

Answer (score 2):

The `netmask`/`network` are needed (theoretically one should suffice AFAIK) to make clear what part of your IP is part of the network prefix bits (the bit that are the same for all hosts on your network, in your case `10.253`) and part is the part of the host bits or rather what your network range is, e.g. hosts can have IPs from `10.253.0.1` to `10.253.255.254` (and if all host bits are set to 1 you get the broadcast address, the address to address all hosts on this network). It's also worth mentioning that your network might be subdivided several times.

The gateway is the address where all packets addressed to outside your network  should go (it's the gateway to the other networks, theoretically you could have several for several other networks but this here is the default gateway responsible for all packets going to networks not explicitly specified in certain routes).

And concerning DNS, you should probably look at Wikipedia, the explanation there is quite good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System